# Calculate the cost of cement for a project

Tags: beginner, c, calculator

I am a newbie in a programming, and I just randomly chose [a task for training from some group on Facebook](https://scontent.fiev10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/46518941_2219787068289887_5720743666285281280_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&_nc_ht=scontent.fiev10-1.fna&oh=de67fd916226fe613a6f9eab7526fd54&oe=5C79CD84). The task is to calculate the cost of cement for a construction project. The input is the number of pounds of cement required (guaranteed not to be a multiple of 120). The store sells cement in 120-pound bags, each costing $45.

Example input: `295.8`
Output: `135`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRICE 45
#define CAPACITY 120
#define MAXDIGITS 5

int sum(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int val = 0;
    char inp[MAXDIGITS];

    if ((argc > 1) && (argv[1] > 0))
        val = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    else
    {
        do 
        {
            printf("Please input the value of cement: ");
            scanf("%s", inp);
            val = strtol(inp, NULL, 0);
        }
        while (!val);
    }

    if (val)
        printf("Money you need: %d\n", sum(val));

    return 0;
}

int sum(int need)
{
    int mon = PRICE;
    int n = CAPACITY;

    while (n < need)
    {
        n += CAPACITY;
        mon += PRICE;
    }

    return mon;
}
```

I'm interested in code style, rational memory usage, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome on Code Review

### Review

```
#define PRICE 45
#define CAPACITY 120
#define MAXDIGITS 5
```

- You define `PRICE` and `CAPATITY` as integers, but a price can have cents, and a bag can maybe contains more than a plain amount in pounds, maybe some ounces more. So you should use decimals here.

```
if ((argc > 1) && (argv[1] > 0))
```

- Don't compare a `char*` to an `int`. This check doesn't insure that `argv[1]` is a valid number.
- If the parameter isn't what you want, you can either print the usage and quit, or silently continue and ask for input.

```
val = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
```

- You don't validate the program argument. `strtol` can silently fail and return "0". In this case, a good option would be to ask for a good input.
- You parse the string to an unsigned integer; but the asked task stand asking a decimal number (and show "295.8" in the example). You could use `strtod` or `atof` but since you are a conscientious programmer, you want to check for validity.

  So the combo `scanf`/`sscanf` (with `"%f"` or `"%lf"`)` are the solution.

```
do 
{
    printf("Please input the value of cement: ");
```

- Try to put a `\n`before your request. It will make the output more clear. Otherwise, it will print on the same line as last output.

```
scanf("%s", inp);
val = strtol(inp, NULL, 0);
```

- As above, use `scanf("%lf", ...)` instead (shorter, and you can check for errors)

```
int sum(int need)
```

Once what i said above is fixed (price and capacity as `double`) your function work fine. However, you can simplify it, by doing the computation in only one line (which can be simplified even more, with libmath).

Here's my corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRICE 45.
#define CAPACITY 120.

int sum(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double need = 0.;

    if (argc < 2 || sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &need) != 1) {
        while (printf("\nPlease input the amount of cement you need (e.g. 295.8): ") && scanf("%lf", &need) != 1) {
            for(int c = 0; c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar());
        } 
    }
    printf("For %.02lf pounds you need: $%.02lf!\n", need, PRICE * ((int)((int)(need / CAPACITY) * CAPACITY < need) + (int)(need / CAPACITY)));

    // or with "#include <math.h>" and the compiler/linker flag "-lm"
    //printf("For %.02lf pounds you need: $%.02lf!\n", need, PRICE * ceil(need / CAPACITY));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agree with you. Only one small mark for your code. If it receive a characters instead of digits, it enters to infinite loop. I think there is no alternative to use additional variable to avoid that possibility.

Comment: @DmitryKhaletskiy fixed

Comment: Sorry, but this code is severely lacking and definitely not something that should be used in place of the OP's much more readable code. The calculations badly need to be split over several lines. Arbitrary checking the return value of printf is fishy. C programming isn't about writing as few LOC as possible, if that comes at the expensive of readability.

Comment: `while (... scanf("%lf", &need) != 1) {` is an infinite loop on end-of-file, input error.

Comment: `(int)` unnecessarily limits a floating-pint function to the `int` range - promoting a weak programing paradigm.  Robust code would use `rint()`, `round()`, `trunc()` etc. instead.

Comment: Code that follows the width of the presentation with of the site (about 92 here) is easier to read and review.  Consider re-formatting.  Should be easy with an auto formatter.

Comment: Why is code checking the return value of `printf()` against 0?  A negative value indicates error.  If the value is to be ignored, consider `,` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Concerning "Try to put a \nbefore your request.", consider [Why use trailing newlines instead of leading with printf?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/381711/94903).

Comment: @chux about the casting, did you notice the commented lines? And here, casting do the job. I didn't say to don't using libmath, just that in this case we can go without. (and I showed how to do with `libmath` too just in case). Also, you have 600 characters to put your message, you don't need to post 5 times in a row.

Comment: I did not notice the commented out code. The comments were separate as they cover different subjects over time.

Comment: I don't recommend using floating-point types for financial quantities - use a type where hundredths can be precisely represented instead.  For most uses, a suitable type is fixed-precision representation, using integers to represent each 0.01 of the value.

Answer (score 2):

### Buffer overflow

Consider what entering `"295.8"` does.

```
#define MAXDIGITS 5
char inp[MAXDIGITS];
printf("Please input the value of cement: ");
scanf("%s", inp);
```

Code used the dangerous `scanf("%s", inp);` with no width limits.  `scanf("%s", inp);` being ignorant of the size of `inp[]`, stored the 5 read characters **and** the appended *null character*.

This results in *undefined behavior* (UB).  Code may work as expected today and fail in strange ways tomorrow.

I recommend to only use `fgets()` for user input.  After reading a *line* of user input, it is saved as a *string*.  Then parse the string.

No need for such a tight buffer size.  Recommend twice the expected max width needed.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE (2*MAXDIGITS + 1)
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

printf("Please input the value of cement: ");
fflush(stdout);  // Insure output is seen before reading

fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
double val = strtod(buffer, NULL);
```